# MS Access Double Type

Tags: ms-access, double

I have a query that compares a value. Both values are equal. Data types are double. However, the result is always false. Have you encountered the same scenario?

I tried to round off the data before comparing it and I got the correct results. What do you think is the cause of this issue?

Comment: Can you please Dlookup() both of the values in the Immediate window to verify equality? Can you repeat the query comparing two rows, both with a single integer entered by hand?

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known side effect of floating numbers.

You have several options. Test for a difference or convert to other data type:

```
Where Abs(Field1 - Field2) < 0.00001  (or whatever value you consider equal)
Where CCur(Field1) = CCur(Field2)
Where CDec(Field1) = CDecCur(Field2)
```

Comment: Hi, Gustav. I cant use Abs, CCur or CDec funtions since I dont want to alter the data. I tried to round off the value and got what I need. What do you think is the issue when Im not rounding off the data?

Comment: Abs doesn't alter the data, but rounding off does. So I can't follow you.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the values are equal for both variables. Double is floating point with 15 decimal precision, I think. If your display is showing your double variables with rounding, they may appear equal but in fact they may not be equal.

I would recommend you to do `Round(variable1, 4)` and compare it with `Round(variable2, 4)`. Try testing your variables with a test routine like this:

```
Public Sub SendDoubles()
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double

    a = 10.0000000001
    b = 10.000000001

    TestDoubles a, b
End Sub

Public Sub TestDoubles(a As Double, b As Double)

    MsgBox CStr(a) & vbCrLf & CStr(b)
    MsgBox a = b
    MsgBox Round(a, 4) = Round(b, 4)

End Sub
```

Notice that `CStr` will convert your double to string so that you can visualize both variable's value. The 2nd MsgBox attempts to compare them as-is and the third one compares them with rounding.

Comment: actually, the values in db are all just the same. no decimal points

Comment: Two doubles with the same data will result in true when compared with `=`. Please post some of your code and data

Comment: The normal precision of a double is 53 binary digits, equivalent to about 15.95 decimal digits. Considering two doubles to be equal if they match to four decimal places is unusual.